# Windows 10: "Disable-NetAdapter" disconnect the hardware Bluetooth from the computer instead of turning it OFF

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, powershell, bluetooth

The Bluetooth worked fine until I run `Disable-NetAdapter *` and then `Enable-NetAdapter *`. It was supposed to just turn OFF/ON all net adapters (including Bluetooth), but it actually disconnects the Bluetooth hardware (I guess it's a bug).

After these PowerShell commands, the Bluetooth only show in device manager in "view hidden device". And in device manager, each item listed under the BT I get `Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer`.

[Someone](https://superuser.com/a/1364134/235752) having the same problem solved it by physically exchanging the Bluetooth hardware, with another one, and reboot. The BT reappeared. Then exchanging back with the first hardware worked: when he rebooted, the BT hardware was then recognized/reconnected.

**Is there a PowerShell command to reset the Bluetooth hardware connection to the computer, and then try to detect it again?**

To Microsoft: this bug seems related (and maybe the root of) [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1153912/bluetooth-setting-disappeared-from-both-settings-and-device-manager/1364141#1364141) kind of issue.

---

- the problem happens on  Windows 10 1809, and also in 1903.

I tried:

- uninstalling the Bluetooth driver, which was shown (before this in the device manager/hidden view) and reboot. Still no Bluetooth.
- I tried to use [this](https://pastebin.com/DhiJc6mD) code (a modified version of Ben's code in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1293303) answer). When I run it sends the error, `Start-Service bthserv`, so run `Get-Service bthserv | Start-Service`. And when I run Ben's code again it output: `Wi-Fi On`.

Comment: If Bluetooth is somehow disabled using rfkill, you need the vendor-specific software for Windows to turn it on again. Alternatively, there may be a working switch in the Action Center (Win+A).

Comment: @DanielB thanks! but when the bug occurs, the Bluetooth hardware isn't detected, so there no switch shown. The switch only turns it ON/OFF. The problem I'm talking about it outright disconnects the hardware from the laptop (Dell Inspiron 3520).

Comment: @DanielB `you need the vendor-specific software for Windows to turn it on again` are you talking about the drivers or something else? (because I installed the drivers provided by an MS technician, and it did not works, somehow it works a few days after (I suspect a windows technician did remotely/secretly reconnected it)

Comment: No, I am talking about something equivalent to the [Software Wireless Switch discussed here](https://ccit.college.columbia.edu/knowledgebase/article/how-manage-wireless-lenovo-laptops). On Linux, there’s `rfkill`.

Comment: @DanielB oh that looks very interesting! Do you think I could reconnect it to windows using a portable linux (or dual partition)? Or maybe reconnecting in Linuw would reconnect it also on windows?

Comment: this answer is interesting: https://askubuntu.com/a/98719/466989 `"Hard blocked" cannot be changed by software, look for a wifi toggle on your keyboard or edges of the laptop; the device can also be hard blocked if disabled in the bios.

"Soft blocked" means "blocked by software". A faulty driver or other kernel module can lead to connectivity loss.`

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the answer, but I wrote [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1444847/235752) for this question (the main thread about the bluetooth bug) that might help some people getting lost on this thread.